# Padding in UITextField

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is it possible to set padding inside a UITextField, if so how?

Comment: See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone)

Answer (score 5):

I was also wondering, here you are:

```
UIView paddingView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 5, 20));
YourTextField.LeftView = paddingView;
YourTextField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

You can modify padding size of course by changing values above.

Hope this will help.

Comment: UITextField does not contain definition for LeftView.

Comment: Worked great for me in a Custom renderor. I put it on the right as follows:
                 UIView paddingView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 40, 20));
                //paddingView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red; //for testing
                Control.RightView = paddingView;
                Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;