# Set padding for UITextField with UITextBorderStyleNone

Tags: ios, uitextfield, padding

I wanted to use a custom background for my `UITextFields`. This works fine except for the fact that I have to use `UITextBorderStyleNone` to make it look pretty. This forces the text to stick to the left without any padding.

Can I set a padding manually so that it looks similar to `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` except for using my custom background image?

Answer (score 876, accepted):

I found a neat little hack to set the left padding for this exact situation.

Basically, you set the leftView property of the `UITextField` to be an empty view of the size of the padding you want:

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Worked like a charm for me!

In **Swift 3/ Swift 4**, it can be done by doing that

```
let paddingView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 20))
textField.leftView = paddingView
textField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, except I needed padding to the right which is mostly the same, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @Lukasz I added an autorelease to this answer, the accepted answer. First line. EDIT: oops, maybe I didn't save? or my edit was rejected? Either way, Vincent added in an autorelease, so yay for that!

Comment: This works great but when i am using same View for multiple UITextfield then it's not working showing me white page.Is the same happend with you too?

Comment: Using ARC, why does my app hang and use a lot of CPU if I reuse `*paddingView` with multiple text fields?

Comment: It's a bad solution, better go for Nate Flink's one. Thios one doesn't include editiong mode padding.

Comment: I did create a custom method by using this Trick and have added an answer in this thread! This perfectly works on iOS 7!
Thanks Evil Trout!!! (Y)
Following is the Answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22471157/1752988

Comment: It is not working with multiple textfields. Just consumes so much memory and later crashes.

Comment: @gbesler try to release the view and again alocate the memory of view and then asing it to different text field. It will work. I had same issue and I solved it with this.

Comment: Not sure if anyone else experienced this, but the subviews added do not respond to touches/taps, so if the user taps on the area where the `UIView` resides the textfield does not become `firstResponder`. In order to get around this issue, a possible fix can be to add a gesture recognizer to the view with `becomeFirstResponder` as the selector.

Comment: @coco yes, i am having this issue but why so?? i ended up subclassing UITextField, & it worked.

Comment: @Alok I assume it's because a single UIView cannot be placed in two different spots at the same time. (Strange coincidence: I ran into this same problem again tonight! I'm so glad you reminded me..)

Comment: Yes, this is kind of hack but when used in certain way works good and when that padding is just small it is not problem that it consume clicks...

Comment: Can some one look at the similar problem but the padding is on the right side. I do not want to mess up with leftview and right view, as I need it for some other purpose.

Comment: why this is accepted and has 700+ ups? It doesn't add padding to left. For example, what if I already use textfield's leftView for something?

Comment: 700 ups (I would up it again if I can) because it works as a hack. If you're using the leftView for something then you... need another solution ;)

Answer (score 184):

I created this category implementation and added it to the top of the `.m` file.

```
@implementation UITextField (custom)
    - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
        return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 8,
                          bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 16);
    }
    - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
        return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
    }
@end
```

Based off the link Piotr Blasiak provided. It seemed simpler then creating a whole new subclass, and also simpler then adding the additional `UIView`. Still, it seems like something is missing to not be able to control the padding inside a text field.

Swift 4 solution:

```swift
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    struct Constants {
        static let sidePadding: CGFloat = 10
        static let topPadding: CGFloat = 8
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(
            x: bounds.origin.x + Constants.sidePadding,
            y: bounds.origin.y + Constants.topPadding,
            width: bounds.size.width - Constants.sidePadding * 2,
            height: bounds.size.height - Constants.topPadding * 2
        )
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws warnings about categories overriding methods.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622779/659989) to suppress them.

Comment: I prefer not doing this in a category, but other than that this is a cleaner solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: It's better to use CGRectInset() for something like this, instead of rolling your own.  It's a little cleaner looking as well: return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 8);

Comment: @EgeAkpinar but what if we want different padding in all four sides ..? Can we use `CGRectInset` in this case ..?

Comment: @shashwat yes, you can specify any padding you'd want

Comment: When I added this 4 years ago, things were different with iOS, and I agree that now it is best to create a subclass. However, if you just want a fast and dirty way to visually inspect your pixel distances, this will do it ;) So its ok for people keep voting!!

Answer (score 147):

A Swift 3 version for Xcode >6, where you can edit the inset value in Interface Builder / Storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class FormTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var inset: CGFloat = 0

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the form text field on mine.

Comment: I needed to add this line `override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset)
  }`

Comment: This answer would be more helpful with an explanation or link to explanation of what `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` do, [i.e. this post at nshipster](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

Comment: If you are relying on any accessory views (such as the clear button functionality on UITextField) then `return super.textRectForBounds(CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset))` will handle the offset from the accessory views properly.

Comment: @okysabeni you need to click on your textfield and change the Class to FormTextField

Comment: Swift 3 > Go to "Show Identity Inspector" Add your "Custom Class". In this example. Add "FormTextField" in Custom Class.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, because it does not cause the text to jump around when editing starts like the accepted answer does.

Comment: About `textRect(forBounds: bounds)`, the documentation explicitly mentions not to call it directly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619636-textrect

Comment: @Pierre If you look at the code, this isn't happening and it's not calling the super method that the documentation states not to call. You're instructed to override it, which is what is happening, and then editingRect is calling the overridden version, which in turn just calls bounds.insetBy.

Answer (score 79):

**Edit: Still works in iOS 11.3.1**

In iOS 6 `myTextField.leftView = paddingView;` is causing issue

This solves the problem

```
myTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0)
```

For right aligned text field use `CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-5, 0, 0)` as mention by *latenitecoder* in comments

Comment: Nice, I had to put the padding in all textfields of the app, I created a category of UITextField and put this code inside -(void)awakeFromNib{} and this solved my problem

Comment: So simple! Thx :) I have a question how can I make a simple code to make all UITextField instead of writing the code many time?

Comment: Yeah I have read that comment but couldn't know how and where to write it. @InderKumarRathore

Comment: All the other comments assume you want to pad a UITextField from the left. Subclassing is a lot of overhead to add some spacing id rather just add some blank characters but this solution is THE solution. One line future proof. If you are working with a textfield that is text right aligned use minus value (-5,0,0) Thanks Inder

Comment: This has recently stopped working for me, looks fine in simulator but on device the text and placeholders are not visible and in fact appear hidden in the center of the screen (double tapping to paste shows pointer there)

Comment: After 4yrs I found my own answer :D , @latenitecoder your comment was what is needed. Updating the answer

Comment: what can i do if i want both right and left padding ??

Comment: This gives me problems when using the textfield in password mode + when the text will get longer than the frame and the punctuation starts.

Answer (score 71):

A good approach to add padding to UITextField is to subclass and add an edgeInsets property.  You then set the edgeInsets and the UITextField will be drawn accordingly.  This will also function correctly with a custom leftView or rightView set.

**OSTextField.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OSTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;

@end
```

**OSTextField.m**

```
#import "OSTextField.h"

@implementation OSTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super editingRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

@end
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. It also works for right and left views..

Answer (score 25):

Just subclass UITextField like this:

```
@implementation DFTextField


- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 10.0f, 0);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}


@end
```

This adds horizontal padding of 10 points either side.

Answer (score 23):

1. Create a textfield Custom

> PaddingTextField.swift

```
import UIKit
class PaddingTextField: UITextField {

@IBInspectable var paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var paddingRight: CGFloat = 0

override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + paddingLeft, bounds.origin.y,
        bounds.size.width - paddingLeft - paddingRight, bounds.size.height);
}

override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return textRectForBounds(bounds)
}}
```

2. Set your textfield class is PaddingTextField and custom your padding as you want
   [image]
   [image]
3. Enjoy it

[image: final]

Answer (score 21):

**Objective C Code**

MyTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat padding;

@end
```

MyTextField.m

```
#import "MyTextField.h"

IB_DESIGNABLE
@implementation MyTextField

@synthesize padding;

-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, padding, padding);
}

-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Comment: About `[self textRectForBounds:bounds];`, the documentation explicitly mentions not to call it directly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619636-textrect

Answer (score 18):

Based on Evil Trout's answer you might wanna create a category to make it easier to use across multiple applications.

Header file:

```
@interface UITextField (PaddingText)

-(void) setLeftPadding:(int) paddingValue;

-(void) setRightPadding:(int) paddingValue;
@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "UITextField+PaddingText.h"

@implementation UITextField (PaddingText)

-(void) setLeftPadding:(int) paddingValue
{
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, paddingValue, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.leftView = paddingView;
    self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}

-(void) setRightPadding:(int) paddingValue
{
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, paddingValue, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.rightView = paddingView;
    self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}

@end
```

Usage Example

```
#import "UITextField+PaddingText.h"

[self.YourTextField setLeftPadding:20.0f];
```

Hope it helps you out guys

Cheers

Answer (score 16):

Swift version:

```
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var padding_left: CGFloat {
        get {
            LF.log("WARNING no getter for UITextField.padding_left")
            return 0
        }
        set (f) {
            layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(f, 0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

So that you can assign value in IB

[image: IBInspectable setting represented in Interface Builder]

Comment: `IBInspectable` allows you to apply the setter code at runtime, so simply put your number in `Interface Builder` and it will work.

Comment: This will not work when you have `Clear Button`. Your clear button will not visible if apply this solution.

Answer (score 12):

You can't set padding. Instead have a `UIView` which has your background image and the `UITextField` inside of it. Set the `UITextField` width as `UIViewWidth-(paddingSize x 2)` and the height similarly and then set it at point `paddingSize,paddingSize`.

Answer (score 11):

Just subclass **UITextField** like this (**Swift version**):

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
       return CGRectInset(bounds, 25.0, 0)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
       return self.textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }

}
```

This adds horizontal padding of **25.0** points either side.

Answer (score 8):

I was based off Nate's solution, but then i found it that this causes problems when you use the leftView/rightView properties, so its better tune the super's implementation, because it will take the left/right view's into account.

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect ret = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    ret.origin.x = ret.origin.x + 5;
    ret.size.width = ret.size.width - 10;
    return ret;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Updated version for Swift 3:

```
@IBDesignable
class FormTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var paddingRight: CGFloat = 0

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + paddingLeft, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width - paddingLeft - paddingRight, height: bounds.size.height)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Set padding for UITextField with UITextBorderStyleNone: Swift

Based on @Evil Trout's most voted answer I created a custom method in my ViewController class, like shown bellow:

```
- (void) modifyTextField:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
    textField.leftView = paddingView;
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.rightView = paddingView;
    textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [textField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Now I can call that method inside (viewDidLoad method) and send any of my TextFields to that method and add padding for both right and left, and give text and background colors by writing just one line of code, as follows:

```
[self modifyTextField:self.firstNameTxtFld];
```

This Worked perfectly on iOS 7!
I know that adding too much Views might make this a bit heavier class to be loaded. But when concerned about the difficulty in other solutions, I found myself more biased to this method and more flexible with using this way. ;)

Thanks for the Hack "Evil Trout"! (bow)

I thought I should update this answer's code snippet with Swift:

Since Swift allow us to write extensions for the existing classes, let's write it in that way.

```
extension UITextField {
    func addPaddingToTextField() {
        let paddingView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 20))
        self.leftView = paddingView;
        self.leftViewMode = .Always;
        self.rightView = paddingView;
        self.rightViewMode = .Always;

    
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
self.firstNameTxtFld.addPaddingToTextField()
```

Hope this would be helpful to somebody else out there! 
Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to achieve this in SWIFT

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, self.yourTextField.frame.height))
yourTextField.leftView = paddingView
yourTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
}
}
```

[Resource](https://medium.com/@deepdeviant/how-to-set-padding-for-uitextfield-in-swift-2f830d131f40)

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 2.0 Version:**

```
let paddingView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20))
textField.leftView = paddingView
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is looking for `Swift 4.0` version then below `extension` is work. It has both `Left` and `Right` padding for `UITextField`. Actually it is `IBInspectable` for storyboard configuration. You can set the value directly from the Interface Builder / Storyboard. This is tested code in Swift 4.0 version and Xcode 9.0

Keep in mind that if you want to enable `Clear Button` on the same `UITextField` then your have to keep Right Padding blank.

```
import UIKit

extension UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var paddingLeft: CGFloat {
        get {
            return leftView!.frame.size.width
        }
        set {
            let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.size.height))
            leftView = paddingView
            leftViewMode = .always
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var paddingRight: CGFloat {
        get {
            return rightView!.frame.size.width
        }
        set {
            let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.size.height))
            rightView = paddingView
            rightViewMode = .always     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

^ these suggestions are great for those who are programmatically creating an interface.

But there are two LAZY EASY WAYS for those of us who use the Xcode interface builder:

- easier: put a UIImageView behind a text field
- **easiest: change the border style on your to the simple black square (second from left option), then add your image as a background image.** The image takes precedence over the square, so you still get the padding needed for a normal image background, without the square actually being drawn on.

EDIT: you can also use the black sphere (third from left option when selecting the UITextBox in IB), it does not work with the far right, "graphical sphere" style.

Comment: Your easier solution is indeed a valid choice in some cases, but your easiest solution is a hack, which also does not work if your image's edge pixels have variable alpha (not to mention that Apple could change their implementation in a future iOS release).

Comment: I don't disagree with you - thats why I put "lazy easy way" in all caps letters. Its worked fine for me to date.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is simply make a class using subclass of UITextField and in .m file

```
 #import "CustomTextField.h"
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 @implementation CustomTextField


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
 {
  self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

  if (self) {

//self.clipsToBounds = YES;
//[self setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];

self.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,15,46)];
self.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
   }

  return self;

 }
```

by doing this go to your storyboard or xib and click on identity inspector and replace UITextfield with your own "CustomTextField" in class option.

Note: If you simply give padding with auto layout for textfield then your application will not run and show only blank screen.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 Version:

```
class CustomTextField:UITextField{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.init(x: bounds.origin.x + 8, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.textRect(forBounds:bounds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Nate Flink's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416234/4407087)  answer is my favourite, but don't forget about right/left views.
E.g for `UITextField` subclass:

```
override func rightViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let rightViewBounds = super.rightViewRectForBounds(bounds)

    return CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(rightViewBounds) - 10, CGRectGetMinY(rightViewBounds), CGRectGetWidth(rightViewBounds), CGRectGetHeight(rightViewBounds))
}
```

Above code set right padding for `rightView` of `UITextField`.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 Solution**

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

 override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
  return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 10, y: bounds.origin.y + 8, width: bounds.size.width - 20, height: bounds.size.height - 16)
 }

 override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
  return self.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a Swift code to give padding in UITextfield**

```
 func txtPaddingVw(txt:UITextField) {
     let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
     txt.leftViewMode = .Always
     txt.leftView = paddingView
 }
```

**and call using**

```
self.txtPaddingVw(txtPin)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use category. set padding to left and right

UITextField+Padding.h

```
@interface UITextField (Padding)
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat paddingValue;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat leftPadding;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat rightPadding;

//overwrite
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
@end
```

**UITextField+Padding.m**

```
#import "UITextField+Padding.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char TAG_LeftPaddingKey;
static char TAG_RightPaddingKey;
static char TAG_Left_RightPaddingKey;

@implementation UITextField (Padding)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

CGFloat offset_Left=0;
CGFloat offset_Right=0;
if (self.paddingValue>0) {
    offset_Left=self.paddingValue;
    offset_Right=offset_Left;
}else{
    if (self.leftPadding>0){
        offset_Left=self.leftPadding;
    }
    if (self.rightPadding>0){
        offset_Right=self.rightPadding;
    }
}

if (offset_Left>0||offset_Right>0) {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+ offset_Left ,bounds.origin.y ,
                      bounds.size.width- (offset_Left+offset_Right), bounds.size.height-2 );
 }else{
    return bounds;
 }
}



-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop


#pragma maek -setter&&getter
- (CGFloat)paddingValue
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&TAG_Left_RightPaddingKey) floatValue];
}
-(void)setPaddingValue:(CGFloat)paddingValue
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TAG_Left_RightPaddingKey, @(paddingValue), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(CGFloat)leftPadding
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&TAG_LeftPaddingKey) floatValue];
}

-(void)setLeftPadding:(CGFloat)leftPadding
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TAG_LeftPaddingKey, @(leftPadding), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(CGFloat)rightPadding
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&TAG_RightPaddingKey) floatValue];
}

-(void)setRightPadding:(CGFloat)rightPadding
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TAG_RightPaddingKey, @(rightPadding), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

**you can set padding like this**
   self.phoneNumTF.paddingValue=10.f;
or
    self.phoneNumTF.leftPadding=10.f;

Answer (score 1):

@Evil trout's answer is great. I have been using this approach for quite a some time now. The only thing it lacks is "dealing with numerous text fields". I tried other approaches but does not seem to work.

Subclassing UITextField just to add a padding didn't make any sense to me. So, I iterated over all UITextFields to add the padding.

```
-(void) addPaddingToAllTextFields:(UIView*)view {

    for(id currentView in [view subviews]){
        if([currentView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            // Change value of CGRectMake to fit ur need
            [currentView setLeftView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)]];
            [currentView setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        }

        if([currentView respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)]){
            [textfieldarray addObjectsFromArray:[self addPaddingToAllTextFields:currentView]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the method can be called by [self addPaddingToAllTextFields:[self view]];

Comment: Since `textfieldarray` isn't defined in the second `if` block, I used this snippet (thanks!) with success after replacing the contents of the second `if` with `for(id subSubView in [view subviews]){[self addPaddingToAllTextFields:subSubView];}`

Answer (score 1):

Brody's solution worked perfect for me. I have had to add side views on a textfield and add additional padding. So by implementing the custom UIEdgeInsets property to a UITextField subclass I have managed to achieve the task. I'm going to use this new subclass in all of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found so far is a category. That's how I add a 5 points padding to left and right:

```
@implementation UITextField (Padding)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 5, bounds.origin.y,
                      bounds.size.width - 10, bounds.size.height);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

The #pragma's are just for removing the annoying warnings

Comment: The thing with method overloading in categories is, that it will be marked as unused in AppCode, which it is in fact. Good idea, but not very secure because it is easily removed when you run "Optimize imports" (no problem for Xcode users though, but we all know the limited code-centric features)

Comment: Is it a simple bummer category that will apply padding for all text fields in the app?

Comment: @Andy no it applies only when you import it, you will need to create a class UITextField+Padding and import it in the viewcontroller or class you have a textfield with padding

Comment: @MongiZaidi: you are wrong. It gets linked into the executable, whether being imported is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I found it far easier to use a non-editable `UITextView` and set the `contentOffset`

```
uiTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(8, 7);
```

Comment: uiTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-8, -7);

Comment: There is no contentOffset property in UITextField. Maybe a misunderstood of UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is that, if you have more than one `UITextField` where you are adding padding, is to create a separate `UIView` for each textfield - because they cannot be shared.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Attributed String !?!, this is one of the blessing feature of IOS 6.0 :)

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *mps = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            mps.firstLineHeadIndent = 5.0f;
UIColor *placeColor = self.item.bgColor;

textFieldInstance.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My Place Holder" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeColor, NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:7.0f], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : mps}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.layer.borderWidth = 3;
```

will add border, which worked as padding for me.