# editingRectForBounds: how to implement for UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am attempting to adjust the margin on a UITextField, and i have done a bit of research and found that i need to use `editingRectForBounds:` While that should be helpful to most people I find that I need a bit more guidance to make the nessesary code changes. Could someone please point me in the direction of a tutorial or maybe write out just a quick couple steps how i might use `editingRectForBounds:` to adjust the UITextField text?

Ive seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674655/uitextfield-align-left-margin), but am not sure how to make it work.

Thanks for the help!