# How to add space at start of UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I am creating an app that contain multiple `UITextField`. In the textField i have sated border type to none and background image. It display fine, But now my text is started from the lest border which does not look good, like this

[image]

How can i add space at the start of the textfield?

Comment: Your problem seems to be same as this [uitextfield-align-left-margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674655/uitextfield-align-left-margin)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
UILabel * leftView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,7,26)];
leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

textField.leftView = leftView;

textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 9):

You should subclass `UITextField` and override drawText function.

check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) for help
OR
You can do following:

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, height_of_textfiled)];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: does this affect my text? means i am sending the data to the web-service so does this code add any malicious data to my actual text?

Comment: Now the code will work fine. you forgot to mention `leftViewMode`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's @Kalpesh's answer in **Swift 3.x**:

```
let leftView = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0.0, 7, 26))
leftView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

customField.leftView = leftView
customField.leftViewMode = .Always
customField.contentVerticalAlignment = .Center
```

**Swift 4.x**

```
let leftView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 7, height: 26))
leftView.backgroundColor =.clear

customField.leftView = leftView
customField.leftViewMode = .always
customField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 7):

### **Objective c**

**For padding only placeholder this code will work**

```
usernameTF.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"    Your text"];
```

**For padding both placeholder and text of the UITextField this below code will work**

```
usernameTF.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(40, 0, 30);
```

---

### **Swift 3.0**

**For padding only placeholder this code will work**

```
yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "    YourText")
```

**For padding both placeholder and text of the UITextField this below code will work**

```
usernameTF.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(40, 0, 30)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass `UITextField` and override `textRectForBounds` and `editingRectForBounds`.

For example,

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 5, bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 10);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 5, bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 10);
}
```

Comment: credit goes to :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674655/uitextfield-align-left-margin

Comment: Instead of adding a clear background view. This way is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4

```
yourTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the textfield background image in an image view,above the imageview put your textfield a space left.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)textField:(UITextField *) textField didBeginEditing {
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""] || textField.text == NULL) {
       textField.text = @" ";
    }
}
```