# Subclass UITextField to add blank space in begining by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I want to add blank space in the beginning of my UITextField. I am subclassing my UITextfield with the following code. I am not sure what is going wrong here

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 15, bounds.origin.y + 15, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 15, bounds.origin.y + 15, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the end result that you want? I think there should be some proper alternative to this.

Comment: I think you could just do a standard text field and do Textfield.text = " "

Comment: @AntonyRaphel great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `textRectForBounds` and `editingRectForBounds` like this:

CustomTextField.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@property CGFloat inset;

@end
```

CustomTextField.m:

```
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@implementation CustomTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(bounds, _inset, 0);
    return rect;
}


- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(bounds, _inset, 0);
    return rect;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomTextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _textField.inset = 20;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is the one I expected. Great Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UILabel * leftView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,7,26)];
leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


textField.leftView = leftView;

textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

[How to add space at start of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145886/how-to-add-space-at-start-of-uitextfield/17145938#17145938)