# How to use custom UITextField in storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Please let me know how to use this custom `UITextField` in my `UIViewController`

I am using storyboards.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MYTextField : UITextField

@end


@implementation MYTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    int margin = 10;
    CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + margin, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - margin, bounds.size.height);
    return inset;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    int margin = 10;
    CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + margin, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - margin, bounds.size.height);
    return inset;
}
```

Comment: This should not be that hard to answer but i don´t understand exactly what is it that you want to do? Are you using Storyboard? Edit your question and make 4 spaces before you post code, makes it more readable.

Comment: Yes I am using Story board I want to Apply left margin in my textfield and i follow this code but I am unable to Implement this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674655/uitextfield-align-left-margin

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a normal `UITextField`, you have to use your custom `MYTextField`.

In code:

```
MYTextField *myTextField = [[MYTextField alloc] init];
```

If you use Interface Builder:

Select your `UITextField` in your Interface Builder file, go to the `Identity Inspector` and set the correct sub class:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

this code add some margin to left side of text field.
Try this worked for me.