# UITextField's placeholder margin and initial cursor margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a textfield with some placeholder. I want to give the margin of 20PX from left to show the placeholder and also wants to set initial cutsor at same margin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674655/add-lefthand-margin-to-uitextfield

Answer (score 6):

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a subclass of `UITextField` and override the `textRectForBounds:` and `editingRectForBounds:` methods to return an insetted rect.

You could do something similar to:

```
func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return adjustBounds(bounds)
}

func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return adjustBounds(bounds)
}

private func adjustBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var newBounds = bounds
    newBounds.origin.x += 20
    newBounds.size.width -= 20
    return newBounds
}

// If you need to place the UITextField placeholder in the initial 20px, 
// you have to override this method as well to provide the right rect.
func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var newBounds = bounds
    newBounds.origin.x = 0
    newBounds.size.width = 20
    return newBounds
}
```

Reference: [Text inset for UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom UITextField.
Implement following methods and set Inset value as required

```
// placeholder position
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 10);
}

// text position
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For placeholder position:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset( self.bounds , margin position , margin position );
}
```

For text position:

```
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset( self.bounds , margin position ,margin position );
}
```