# How can I make the cursor in a UITextField start a space from the edge using keepLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am adding a UITextField programatically into a tableViewCell and currently the cursor starts right up against the left hand side of the textField. The textFields I have added using the xib file always have a gap here.

Does anyone know how to apply this gap manually?

This is my textField:

[image]

This is what I want my textField to look like:

[image]

Also are there any specifics on the expected dimensions, font, color or a UITextField?

I think the height should be 31 but I'm not sure what other characteristics I should set to make my custom one look like the added xib one.

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT:

Thanks for the help - looking at the answers provided my situation is slightly different as I am using keepLayout rather than setting up a frame with a rectangle. Is there any way to solve this using keepLayout or do I need to use a frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use category for that follow the Bellow steps. You can create category like this:-

[image]

[image]

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextField (mytextFiled)


- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "UITextField+bgImageset.h"

@implementation UITextField (mytextFiled)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {


    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 20, bounds.origin.y + 5,
                      bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 10);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

@end
```

using above category that my `textfiled` Look's Like bellow I am setting image for `textfiled` so that look bit different..

[image]

Comment: please reason with minus vote else prove where i did mistake in this answer.

Comment: +1 for your UI stuff. awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved this in a recent app is this -

`usernameTextField = [[UIView alloc] 
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 40.0f)];
usernameTextField.leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
usernameTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;`

It is not a good practice to extend `UITextField` with a category as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424004/suppress-warning-category-is-implementing-a-method-which-will-also-be-implement).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a `textField.leftView` here you add any view i.e. image or empty view just like

```
    txtField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    txtField.leftView = imageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to @Nitin's. But instead of creating a category, I have subclassed `UITextField` to achieve :

[image]

The code is as follows :

**`.h`** :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface W3BTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;

@end
```

**`.m`** :

```
#import "W3BTextField.h"

@implementation W3BTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.5, 10, 6.5, 5);

    }
   return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super editingRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

@end
```

Now all this is done programmatically, without using `XIB`s/`storyboard`s.

Used in class like this :

```
W3BTextField* registrationFullName = [[W3BTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 25, 260, 35)];

registrationFullName.placeholder = @"Full name";

registrationFullName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];

registrationFullName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x333333);

registrationFullName.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0f;

registrationFullName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

registrationFullName.delegate = self;

[registrationFullName addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```