# How to remove this warning redefinition method in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmppframework

I'm getting a warning into my Objective-c project. The warning is:

> Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by
>   its primary class.

I'm getting this warning into a class of library XMPPFramework [XMPP on github](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

I have the next function in a XMPPMessage.h class

```
 - (BOOL)isGroupChatMessage;
```

And I'm renaming the same named function in the class XMPPMessage +XEP0045.h

How can I delete the warning? What changes will you need to make in the inheritance of the functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424004/suppress-warning-category-is-implementing-a-method-which-will-also-be-implement ? But I'd avoid to override it, I'd rename my own one to avoid collision.

Comment: you should either use a category and provide method names that are new and unique for the class, or subclass if you want to change the behavior of an existing method in a class.