# make the text input to start after some space in textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to make the text input to start after some space in textfield in iPhone?

Comment: You need to create a `UIView` of width say 5, and give `UITextField`'s  `leftView` as that view.  Explained better here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423805/876283

Comment: Do you want leading spaces in your textfield, with the cursor placed after the spaces upon selection?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```

hope this help to you..