# How To Simplify Padding Left and Right for textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I already have solution for creating padding for all of my textfield, but I think I need to simplify it because I think this is too manual :

```
// Padding Left and Right for textfield
UIView *fieldEmail = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldEmail.leftView = fieldEmail;

UIView *fieldPassword = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldPassword.leftView = fieldPassword;

UIView *fieldRegisterName = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldRegisterName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldRegisterName.leftView = fieldRegisterName;

UIView *fieldRegisterEmail = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldRegisterEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldRegisterEmail.leftView = fieldRegisterEmail;

UIView *fieldRegisterPassword = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldRegisterPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldRegisterPassword.leftView = fieldRegisterPassword;
```

can we create loop or something, so that this padding can affect to all of my textfield? how to simplified this?

thank you.

Comment: create category this is best take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone)

Comment: Are you sure that creating your own padding style is the right thing to do WRT the HIG?

Comment: @trojanfoe : what do you mean with WRT and HIG? I don't get it...

Comment: With Respect To the Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may subclass UITextField and override `textRectForBounds`, `editingRectForBounds` and `drawPlaceholderInRect`. This is already done in SSToolkit [`SSTextField`](https://github.com/soffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/SSTextField.h). You may use it like this:

```
textField.textEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 10)
```

If you want to use same insets for all textfield, then just subclass and harcode this values.