# Padding Placeholder text ios

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to make the placeholder text display in middle of the textfield (Padding placeholder text). The size of the placeholder text also needs to increase. My code is as follows, how can i solve this ?

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 220,250,55)];

textField.placeholder=@"iiiiiii";

UIView *padView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 10, 0)];
textField.leftView = padView;
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;


[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

UPDATE

[image]

I want the font size of the placeholder text to increase `your name`, and it should have a Left padding to it.

Comment: Are you asking how to have the `placeholder` text centered in a `UITextField`, but left aligned once the user starts adding `text` into it?

Comment: I have updated my post, I have also added an image to describe my issue.

Answer (score 13):

You could subclass your `UITextFiled` and override methods:

```
MyTextField.m

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self rectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self rectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self rectForBounds:bounds];
}

//here 40 - is your x offset
- (CGRect)rectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 40, 3);
}
```

**upd:**
also set

```
textFiled.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

because it could some problems with io6 vs ios 7 vertical positionning

Comment: What do you mean by problems ?

Comment: a had one in ios6 and ios7 vertical alignment was different with same code and set contentVerticalAlignment help with it.

Answer (score 5):

Same question was being asked and answered as below [Set padding for UITextField with UITextBorderStyleNone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone)

```
  UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
  textField.leftView = paddingView;
  textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the starting text alignment (*of the `textField` from xib or via code*) to be center aligned.
Then in the `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, you can set the `textField` to be left aligned.
Similarly, on the `-textFieldDidEndEditing`, check if the `textField` is empty and if it is then set `textField` back to center aligned.

basically:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.text.length == 0) {
        [textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**:

the **.h** of your `ViewController` class should look like:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> 
{
    UITextField *myTextField;
}
```

now, replace your other code with this:

```
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 220,250,55)];

myTextField.placeholder=@"iiiiiii";

//important
[myTextField setDelegate: self];

//commented lines not really needed
//UIView *padView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 10, 0)];
//textField.leftView = padView;
//textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: So do i need this `[textField setDelegate:self];` , When i add that line it says ` Sending 'ViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>'`

Comment: @sharonHwk : yes, delegate is needed but **also**, in the **.h** of your `ViewController` you need to declare that your Class is using the delegate (*simply by **`<UITextFieldDelegate>`***) ... example: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

Comment: @sharonHwk : but... but... it's not exactly `[textField setDelegate:self];` ... in your `-viewDidLoad` or wherever you create the `UITextField` object, say something like `UITextField *txtFSomething = [UITextField alloc] init];` then you set delegate by `[txtFSomething setDelegate:self];` or you do it via the xib connection.

Comment: I still get the same warning.

Comment: @sharonHwk : where are adding the line `[textField setDelegate:self];` ? also, change the name of ou UITextField Object from `textField` to something else like `myTextField` and then do `[myTextField setDelegate:self];`

Answer (score 1):

```
sampleTextfield.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, self.sampleTextfield.frame.height))
sampleTextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found to do this task on swift 2 and Xcode 7:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, self.emailTextField.frame.height))
        emailTextField.leftView = paddingView
        emailTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func placeholderPadding(textField:UITextField, leftPadding:CGFloat) {
            textField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: leftPadding, height: textField.frame.height))
            textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

While I have not specifically tested it, this should work:

```
self.YourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "    YourText")
```

Add the amount of blank spaces (padding) to your string