# Place UITextView placeholder/text at top-left corner

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, placeholder

The text inside the `UITextView` sits in the middle like so:

[image]

But I would like to place at the top left, rather than hovering somewhere in the middle. Not sure why it happens.

tried using

```
textView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(x, y, z)
```

But it didn't change anything

Edit: The actual margin appears because of the navbar at the top.  I guess it's just like the problem that occurs with a tableview when theres a 64 pixel margin. How can I remove the margin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425281/padding-placeholder-text-ios

Comment: Did U use any library for textview ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835944/uitextview-text-content-doesnt-start-from-the-top

Comment: just try to add blank label above textview in viewcontroller hierarchy @luke

Comment: Use one external library that is SZTextView simple give a class to your TextView and Your Storyboard Automatically Update and You can Put directly placeholder to Your TextView .

Comment: https://github.com/glaszig/SZTextView/tree/master/Classes download this 2 File and put it in your project and give a class to your textview

Comment: @New16 that's textfield and obj-c, not textview/swift

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Doesn't work if I think i did what you said.

Comment: @luke the views are still from objC, what ever is written in Objective-C should be available for swift as well. Only the syntax changes.

Comment: @luke Do textview has a placeholder?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari No, you have to make your own placeholder for uitextview. If you're interested see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift

Comment: @luke Yeah thats ok. but still the text in UITextView is always at top left no matter what size is by default

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
youtextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7.0,0.0,0,0.0);
```

If you're having issues with iOS7 or above, try using...

```
[yourTextView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(x,y) animated:BOOL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: setup the textview inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews` rather than `viewDidLoad`