# Add padding to left margin of UITextField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with a background image set. The background image consists of a border with an icon on the left side. I'd like to move the cursor so the editing starts after the icon appears. How would I accomplish this in swift?

edit: Would it be easier have a custom border as an uimageview and the textfield placed over it and attached to it? If so what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone

Comment: You can use this : https://gist.github.com/namanhams/dc3b491557ec6fb12060

Answer (score 15):

if you want left padding in TextField just use below code ,

```
youTextFiled.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
```

The amount of left padding you can change by changing the value of at first argument .