# Change border width for multiple UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am using 5 to 7 `UITextField` on every `UIViewController` in my project. I want to set border width for all those. I know the code for changing `UITextField` border width:

```
textField.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
```

But for each and every `UITextField` I need to do that. Is there any simple way to achieve that.

Comment: extend UITextField and use that textfield wherever you need...

Comment: Create a category for  UITextfield for such customizations

Comment: I agree with @MuhammadAdnan, create extension (or category in Objective-C) is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the category for making global  setting for UITextField like following:

> FOR CREATE CATEGORY check this answer: [How to give padding to UITextField in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085348/how-to-give-padding-to-uitextfield-in-ios)

**UITextField+setBorder.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextField (setBorder)


-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (void)setBorderForColor:(UIColor *)color
                    width:(float)width
                   radius:(float)radius;
@end
```

**UITextField+setBorder.m**

```
#import "UITextField+setBorder.h"

@implementation UITextField (setBorder)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {


     [self setBorderForColor:[UIColor redColor] width:5 radius:0];
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x , bounds.origin.y ,
                      bounds.size.width , bounds.size.height );  // here you can make coercer position change
}
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {



    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}


- (void)setBorderForColor:(UIColor *)color
                    width:(float)width
                   radius:(float)radius
{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderColor = [color CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = width;
}
```

**OUTPUT IS**

[image]

Comment: :: sorry i am new to iOS, even though i use your code. i think i should call the method for every textfield

Comment: you dont need to call this method after create a category you just need to copy and past its h and m file my code no need to do anythings

Comment: i added borderstyle for your code because i need  UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect  like this:      - (void)setBorderForColor:(UIColor*)color
                    width:(float)width
                   radius:(float)radius borderStyle:(UITextBorderStyle)borderStyle    . but border style is not changing

Answer (score 1):

U can Assign textField.layer.borderWidth=2.0f; in NSObject class then u can inherit the class whenever u need

Answer (score 0):

A best way to create a class subclass of UITextField and write code for border width and colour like stuff in subclass.And give your textfield's super class to created class.You don't need to write code again and again.