# UITextField "content size" property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is there a way to make the right side of a `UITextField`'s content "end sooner" like in this graphic:

[image]

I'm using the following to give the content text some left padding, but can't figure out an easy solution to reduce the available content size on the right size: `self.textfield.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0);`

I'd rather not subclass `UITextField` but I'm fine doing so if need be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set padding for UITextField with UITextBorderStyleNone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone)

Comment: @Kreiri isn't that for left padding?

Answer (score 0):

try these...
i hope it helps..

```
UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 150, 30)];
[txt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[txt setPlaceholder:@"Hello my friend"];
[self.view addSubview:txt];

UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 50, 30)];
txt.rightView = paddingView;
txt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```