# UITextField visible area while editing

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, cgrect

In my Swift 3 application I have several `UITextField` set without border that should be capable to accept user email, password, etc...

Text alignment is set to center and (see attached pic right side) its size is the entire visible screen (leading and trailing constrains to the border).
[image]

The problem is that the visible editable area is not the entire text field but a small portion in its center (see attach on the left).

This makes the UI really awful to look at when typing something as it truncates letters: 
[image]

I've tried using padding or insets in my `UITextField` but it didn't worked well.

Also I tried to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone?rq=1) SO question, but again no joy.

*******************EDIT*****************

These are the constrains to the `UITextField`:
[image]

Comment: It seems you have set leading and trailing constraints incorrectly. Can you show us how you did that?

Comment: Yes, I just posted an update! Thanks. Should I try to clear and re-add the constrains ?

Comment: Your image is showing "This Size Class" selected... Are you *intentionally* setting different constraints for different size classes?

Comment: Mmhhh nope. To be honest I haven't touched 'size classes' at all. I just tried to change to "all" instead of This Size Class, but it doesn't change :-( What's annoying me is that once the editing ends the text field perfectly display the full text without any cut

Comment: Your constraints make no sense. If you have set both leading and trailing it is silly to set center X as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @matt. This doesn't solve the problem by the way :-)

Comment: I know that. But until you have minimal consistent nonambiguous constraints you can't even begin to debug this.