# While typing text in the textField the text clips at the left edge in iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

In iOS 11 devices the text in the textField clips while typing, however after ending editing it appears properly. My textField is centre aligned to the screen

I tried adding a padding view at the beginning of textField. That did not help

This issue happens when the 'textField.borderStyle = .none', for other border styles it appears properly.

Please check the image in the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nsRYuAXtrWf-eK4La1SYX-0-rEKDoFxW/view?usp=sharing of text clipping issue.

Comment: You can add constraints leading and trailing then set textfield editing type is center

Comment: Thank you for the response but this solution does not help me because I have a label after textfield and it should appear together. Please refer the image  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nsRYuAXtrWf-eK4La1SYX-0-rEKDoFxW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share your storyboard with us? It is difficult to understand what is the cause without it.

Comment: Maybe the constraint issue

Comment: I have uploaded the storyboard please refer to the link. The issue is observed in  iOS 0.3 as well.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X5Z5JXOJSSBiiQ74Hl6xmDl9x_AXstPz/view?usp=sharing . Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: The issue is same as the one mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635339/content-of-uitextfiled-gets-trimmed-when-removing-the-border?rq=1 but the solution mentioned there did not work for me