# leftView property of UITextfiled Not working in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

```
textSearchField.hidden = NO;
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 20)];
textSearchField.leftView = paddingView;
textSearchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[search_view addSubview:textSearchField];
```

I want to add left padding - 10 px for `UITextfield` using `Objective-C`. If any other solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone

Comment: I have tried two solutions.
1. category of custom textfield - but it will apply all textfield throughout application .
2. Using lefteview property - the above code is not working for me. there is no change x and y position.

Comment: @BhaveshNayi, all people when getting trouble with code then only will come to stackoverflow. i know this existing questions. i want to know y this code not working for me.

Comment: @Seethalakshmi_user8943692 i think issue is when adding textfield. Check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can create programmatically by using below code:

```
CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
DKTextField* textField = [[DKTextField alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];
textField.padding = 1.0
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Use Below Classes for it

**DKTextField.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DKTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat padding;

@end
```

**DKTextField.m**

```
#import "DKTextField.h"

IB_DESIGNABLE
@implementation DKTextField

@synthesize padding;

-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, padding, padding);
}

-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

@end
```

You just have to give your selected `UITextField` to `DKTextField` Class

[image]

Whatever the padding you want just add it like below image.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this. But it will apply All textfield throughout  application. but i need particular controller only.

Comment: This solution works with single textfield as well, you just need to change the class of text field in the specific view controller and use default text field class for all other controllers.

Comment: Its not in storyboard. programmatically i have created textfield.

Comment: @Seethalakshmi_user8943692 Then you just have to write DKTextField instead if UITextField. That's It.

Comment: @Seethalakshmi_user8943692 I have updated my answer with code of programmatically creation of uitextfield.

Comment: @Seethalakshmi_user8943692 Is this works for you? Do let me know if you still facing issues. Thanks

Comment: Hi, This only working for me. and it will not apply all textfield through out application. its applied my particular controller.Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: @VijaySanghavi Yes you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

//TRY this

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:textField];

UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 20)];
paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Check IMAGE

[image]

Comment: textSearchField.hidden = NO;
    [search_view addSubview:textSearchField];
    
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 20)];
    paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    textSearchField.leftView = paddingView;
    textSearchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

Here, No change x and y position.

Comment: its working or not ?

Comment: No. Not working.

Comment: @Seethalakshmi_user8943692 check my updated answer. and its working fine from my side. Check attached image

Comment: @Seethalakshmi_user8943692 did you checked my updated answer ?

Comment: Yes. but for me x position not changed.

Comment: You need to just change x position ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192610/discussion-between-seethalakshmi-user8943692-and-bhavesh-nayi).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. i have implemented another solution.

Answer (score 0):

textSearchField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, screenWidth - 10 -  40, search_height- 10)];

```
textSearchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textSearchField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textSearchField.placeholder = @"Search...";
textSearchField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textSearchField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textSearchField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
textSearchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textSearchField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textSearchField.delegate = self;

UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 20)];
paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
textSearchField.leftView = paddingView;
textSearchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```